# How to set rotation of a view based on other view position

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I know the question doesn't make a lot of sense, but I have two views.

The first one I set its position `X` & `Y` based on touch event on the activity.

The second one is like an arrow fixed in the middle of the activity and I want it to point exactly where the the first view is positioned.

so is there a way that can convert a view's position coordinates into a angle value based from the center of the screen.?

```
parentView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        marker.setX(event.getX()); // marker is the first view
        marker.setY(event.getY());
        FixedArrow.setRotation(/* ??? */); //FixedArrow is the second view
        return true;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
public float getAngle(Point target, Point center) {
    float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(target.y - center.y, target.x - center.x));

    if(angle < 0){
        angle += 360;
    }

    return angle;
}
```

to call it do something like  this

```
Point target = new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
Point center = new Point(parentView.getWidth()/2, parentView.getHeight()/2);
FixedArrow.setRotation(getAngle(target,center));
```

Comment: can you explain the params here? what should I pass when I call the method?

Comment: It didn't quite work, there's like a 30 degrees difference here, and I think the reason is the casting that I had to make since the Point class takes int values in its constructor! or it can be a totally different reason!

Answer (score 0):

It's task from geometry from middle school. Basically what you need is to solve right triangle. One side of this triangle is always a line from the centre of the screen to the nearest screen border, another one from centre to the point of user click. Applying there trigonometry, you can calculate an angle.

Final formula and explanation with picture for understanding can be found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1596518)